# Distribute a slideshow from IPython notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

so I am adoring the new IPython notebook slideshow feature, however I could not figure out how to distribute such a slideshow in a userfriendly (I am no HTML/JS guy) way.

My usecase is:

I have a somewhat messy notebook which I want to filter by tagging cells as slides/skip/- etc.
In an optimal world there would be a fire-and-forget 'give me a pdf' button somewhere.

So I did already view the slides locally via ipython nbconvert ... --to slides -- post serve

But how do I distribute that to others? Can I get a pdf from such a slideshow easily (I do not care about transition animations etc.)

I hope this is developed further, great features so far!

Comment: I think the command (in the post) has a typo: there should not be a white space between "--" and the "post" (could not edit the post itself as the correction is too short)

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there is only a hackish way, see [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/3993).
You might also try [Slideviewer](http://slideviewer.herokuapp.com/) (in contrast to [NBviewer](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/)).

Answer (score 1):

`$ ipython nbconvert ... --to slides` (no serve option necessary) create a standalone html file you should be able to mail, or whatever.

The skip/- logic can be applied to pdf generation too, you just have to write your own extended template (which is not that hard, wild guess ~20 lines)

Answer (score 1):

You can print it as a pdf file from Chrome.

- Add "?print-pdf" at the end of your URL.e.g: 127.0.0.1:8000/index.html?print-pdf
- Select print menu from Chrome.
- Select Save As pdf, then print it out.

Answer (score 0):

buddy, I'm sure this is what you want

https://github.com/damianavila/RISE

for more details, check here

https://conference.scipy.org/scipy2014/schedule/presentation/1718/